# How do I make a Time Slider to display site Archive in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm thinking something similiar to [this site](http://www.ntvmsnbc.com/). (The slider widget is about a quarter way through the webpage). Something that whenever I slide, the posts between those hours would displayed.

Is there such a plugin available in WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if there is an WordPress plugin available. But maby there is a jQuery plugin available. Or you can maby create it yourself? I think it shouldnt be that hard if you know how to work with JavaScript & jQuery

Comment: Thank you Very much for your reply Rolf Koenders. If possible then please suggest jquery with Demo.

Comment: Maby this helps you out: http://akzhan.github.com/jquery-time-slider/  &  http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/ search for some jquery tuts or sliders maby you find one wich you can modify to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank You very much Rolf for your great support. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem ;) Please click the checkmark that this answered your question =]